# Sympify string expression depending on a real valued argument

Tags: python, sympy

I expect the following code evaluates derivative of `sin(t)`

```
import sympy as sy

t = sy.Symbol('t', real=True)
expr = sy.sympify('sin(t)')
dexpr = sy.diff(expr, t)
print dexpr
```

But actually it prints `0`. If I change the first line by `t = sy.Symbol('t')`, it works well. It looks like sympy thinks there are 2 different `t`.

**The question:** how to say to sympy that my string expression depends on the real valued argument `t`, and how to sympify this string correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you declare *t* as a real variable, it will be considered a different variable to *Symbol('t')* (with no assumptions).

Try this way:

```
In [1]: treal = Symbol('t', real=True)

In [2]: t = Symbol('t')

In [3]: expr = sympify('sin(t)')

In [4]: expr.diff(treal)
Out[4]: 0

In [5]: expr.diff(t)
Out[5]: cos(t)

In [6]: treal == t
Out[6]: False

In [7]: expr_real = expr.subs(t, treal)

In [8]: expr_real.diff(treal)
Out[8]: cos(t)
```

In input [6] you may see that the two variables are considered different, even if both print as *t*. If you differentiate by the real variable your sympified expression (input [4]), your expression will be considered a constant, because the two *t*s do not identify as the same variable.

In input [7] I replaced *t* with *treal*, so that in input [8] I was able to correctly derive the expression.

**EDIT**

A fast form to import is by specifying in *sympify* a mapping between string-variables and local-variables:

```
In [1]: t = Symbol('t', real=True)

In [2]: expr = sympify('sin(t)', locals={'t': t})

In [3]: expr
Out[3]: sin(t)

In [4]: expr.diff(t)
Out[4]: cos(t)
```

In this way, *t* will be set to the variable defined in input [1].

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Substituting looks like a workaround.. Is it possible to define that my string expression is always positive? Maybe using sympy.assume, sympy.simplify, etc.